# Limit with ln without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

This is an extra question in my maths assignment. Quite easy with L'Hôpital's, but I can't do it without the rule.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $$\frac{4x+5}{4x-5}=\frac{4x-5+10}{4x-5}=1+\frac{10}{4x-5}.$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{4x+5}{4x-5}\right)^x&=\exp\left\{x\log\!\left(1+\frac{10}{4x-5}\right)\right\}\\[.4em]&=\exp\left\{x\left(\frac{10}{4x-5}+o\!\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\right\}\\[.4em]
&=\exp\left(\frac{10x}{4x-5}\right)\Bigl(1+o(1)\Bigr),
\end{align*}
which shows that $$\left(\frac{4x+5}{4x-5}\right)^x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\:\mathrm e^{\frac{10}4}=\sqrt{\mathrm e^5}.$$

---

*Other (more stupid) way.* \begin{align*}\left(\frac{4x+5}{4x-5}\right)^x&=\left[\left(1+\frac{10}{4x-5}\right)^{\!\frac{4x-5}{10}}\right]^{\frac{10}4}\cdot\left(1+\frac{10}{4x-5}\right)^{\!\frac54}\\[.4em]&\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\:\bigl[\mathrm e\bigr]^{\frac{10}4}\cdot1=\sqrt{\mathrm e^5}.\end{align*}

Comment: Please know that this site has an expectation of quality standards, for both askers, but also for answerers;  if a question is a problem statement only, with not context, answerers are expected to not answer it, unless or until the question is improved.  For more details, see [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|141.5973)